# Want to Gather all nav tabs into icon on page zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My navigation bar working perfectly but when i zoom it so it is disappear.

i want when certain zoom will be done so all the nav link should bind into one icon. how can i achieve it, please help

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dasdasd</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/header.css">
</head>
<header>
<body>
<nav>

<div class="box_one">
<a href="/index">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="logo" title="logo" width="90px">
</a>
</div>

<div class="box_two">
<ul>
        <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About Us</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href="/city">City</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href="/how">How it works</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>

</ul>

</div>



<!-- <div class="box_three">
<ul>
    <li><img src="img/login.png" width="30px" alt="login" title="login" align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Login</li>
    <li><img src="img/signup.png" width="30px" alt="signup" title="signup" align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign Up</li>
</ul>

</div>
 -->

</nav>
</header>
```

My CSS

```
body{margin:0px;}
        nav{font-family: calibri;width: 100%; min-height: 80px; max-height: 140px; background: #3a3a3a; color: white;}
        .box_one{width: 180px;float: left;height: 80px;margin-left: 30px;}
        .box_two{font-size: 18px;width: 70%;float: left;height: 80px;margin-left: 8%;}
        .box_three{font-size: 18px;width: 320px;float: right;height: 80px;margin-left: 10px;}

nav a{text-decoration:none;color: white;}
nav li
{
    margin-top: 26px;
   display:block;
   float:left;
   min-height:150px; 
   max-height:200px; 
   padding: 5px; 
   list-style: square outside none;
    padding-left: 1em; 
    text-indent: -.7em;
}
.box_two li
{
   min-width:60px; 
   max-width:120px; 
}
.box_three li
{
   width:93px; 
}
 nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

For example i have uploaded code on jsfiddle [please check](https://jsfiddle.net/t2zamxsz/)
When you will zoom out so it is showing on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should you bootstrap for this, It will make your life easy. If you don't want to use bootstrap you have to use CSS media queries for all resolution which is not cool. I have created an example of menu bar using bootstrap for you here it is. for more info refer [getBootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
  </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

----- UPDATE -----
You have to modify media queries as per you requirement currently I have adjusted menu so it will be visible even if you zoom it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dasdasd</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/header.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      body{margin:0px;}
        nav{font-family: calibri;width: 100%; min-height: 80px; max-height: 140px; background: #3a3a3a; color: white;}
        .box_one{width: 180px; float: left; height: 80px;margin-left: 30px;}
        .box_two{font-size: 18px; float: left;height: 80px;}
        .box_three{font-size: 18px;width: 320px;float: right;height: 80px;margin-left: 10px;}

nav a{text-decoration:none;color: white;}
nav li
{
  margin-top: 26px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding: 5px; 
  padding-left: 1em; 
}
.box_three li
{
   width:93px; 
}
 nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  header{ width:100% !important;}
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  header{ width:100% !important;}
  .box_one{width: 100px; margin-left: 5px;}
  
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.button05 {margin: 10px 0 0;width: 100%;}
 .box_one{width: 100px; margin-left: 0px;}
 .box_two {
    font-size: 12px; 
    float: none;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
 header{ width:100% !important;}
  .box_one{width: 100px; margin-left: 0px;}
  .box_two {
    font-size: 12px;
    float: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}


    </style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<nav>

<div class="box_one">
<a href="/index">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="logo" title="logo" width="90px">
</a>
</div>

<div class="box_two">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/city">City</a></li>
    <li><a href="/how">How it works</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation, but my whole web without bootstrap working perfectly just my nav bar doing problem, therefore i ask for it. Can you give solution without bootstrap

Comment: in that case you have to write CSS media queries for menu bar classes.

Comment: can you help for it?